# How to add conditional fields in force:recordData

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, force-recorddata

I am getting an error while loading my aura components due to some of the lookup fields does not have any value. In our data model we have a lookup to an Account from Account. It's setup as a customer belonging to a company (employer) which is a lookup. The customer may or may not have an employer associated.

I have a following code in a component in which I am getting an error.

```
<aura:component controller="CustomerAccountsController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="acc" type="Account" />

    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetFields="{!v.acc}"
                      fields="external_id__c, Employer__r.external_id__c"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.recordLoaded}"
                      />
    ......
</aura:component>
```

The Employer__c lookup may or may not be present for all the individual account record. While loading a component error like following:

```
Action failed: c:accountDetails$controller$recordLoaded [Cannot read property 'external_id__c' of null]
```

Any idea how I can conditionally say in fields that if Employer is null then dont look for Employer__r.external_id__c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your JavaScript, use the && operator:

```
var externalId = record.Employer__r && record.Employer__r.external_id__c;
```

Make sure that you use the proper case, as JavaScript is `cAsE-sEnSiTiVe`.

Comment: Thank you. Always helpful. I was about to answer my own question but your reply was already here. Best,